# How to chain subscriptions and return a single observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

i m trying to chain 3 subscriptions in a service and return an observable so all the components can subscribe single observable. When i console.log "_campaigns" its always empty. I believe some sync. problem there. the I m new to Rx.js, any ideas how could i achieve this ?

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: didnt work out.. somehow its not triggered when i subscribe it in the component

Comment: i subscribe this inside of a component but dont get any results

Comment: did your streams compete or not? forkJoin will fire only when all streams are completed. Like i wrote, if streams are continous, use mergeAll. If order matters use switchMap/contactMap

Comment: also used mergeAll and combineLatest but no luck.. not trigerred... updated the question. Maybe not working because of subjects ?

Comment: Just create a stackblitz and somewone will fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If those are single shot streams (like http requests) then `forkJoin` and you are good to go

```
forkJoin([
 this.cmsListSuccessSub$,this.userListSuccessSub$,this.publicListSuccessSub$
]).pipe(map(arr=>([...arr[0],...arr[1],...arr[2])).subscribe((allItems)=>this._cmsCampaigns = items)
```

If those are continous, use `mergeAll`

Comment: I can see that not all of thos streams are of the same type thus this will render obvious type error, but you should get the idea. Each array element corresponds to the observable that produced it

Comment: where would i use reloadCampaigns and appendCampaigns methods ? and how would i return an observable ?

Comment: forkJoin returns an observable. In my example I subscibe to it. In your case you will just return it.

Comment: but in first subscription reloadCampaigns happening and on second one appendCampaigns. in this solution how can i differ them ?

Comment: you jsut do it in `map` forkJoin emmits results of all 3 observables at once.

Comment: getting syntax error, updated my question